# Getting data from one cell every 24hrs and transferring that data to another sheet with date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am looking to dynamically create a chart within my google sheet, by taking data from a cell every 24hrs.

Then plotting that data to a chart. I only require this to be within the sheet, and no external site.

Is this possible? will I have to use something like google scripts to get this done? And how can i get that script to run every 24hrs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up a Script with Apps Script that gets the data from your cell and inserts it to another cell.
For the chart, once you have it created for the first time and linked with an specific range of cells, it will automatically update every time the values change.

To run it every 24h you have to set up a **Time-driven trigger**

See:

[Apps Script sheets reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

[Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)